# float number's machine representation is not my expecting result

Tags: c++, floating-point, cpu-architecture

According to the IEEE754 standard, 

the float type number -1.1f should be represented like this(in hex format):

BF8CCCCCH.

since -1.1 = -1.00011[0011]... = -1.000 1100 1100 1100 1100 1100,

the signed field should be 1

the exponent field should be 127 + 0 = 01111111

so the binary format is:

1 01111111 000 1100 1100 1100 1100 1100=BF8CCCCCH

But the experiment's result is not what i expected.

Here's the code:

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstdint>

int main()
{
    float f = -1.1f;
    uint32_t* pf = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(&f);
    printf("%x", *pf);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I build it by CodeBlocks and Visual Studio seperately, both print the result BF8CCCCD, which is not equal to BF8CCCCC.

Comment: regarding: *I build it by CodeBlocks and Visual Studio seperately, both print the result BF8CCCCD, which is not equal to BF8CCCCD.*  Perhaps you meant the second hex value to be: `BF8CCCCC`

Comment: You neglected to consider the effects of rounding.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Could you explain it more specifically?

Comment: @user3629249 Thanks for your reminding

Comment: You assumed it truncated the infinite sequence of 1100 digits.  It rounded it.

Comment: 0xBF8CCCCD is correct. The lower bits must be rounded in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a decimal numeral is converted to binary floating-point, the bits are not just chopped off. Instead, the number is rounded to the nearest representable value.

In your case, where the exact binary value would be  -1.000 1100 1100 1100 1100 1100 1100…, with 1100 repeating forever, the result -1.000 1100 1100 1100 1100 1101 is closer to the exact value than -1.000 1100 1100 1100 1100 1100 is. The (absolute value of the) difference between these two numbers:

```
-1.000 1100 1100 1100 1100 1100 1100…
-1.000 1100 1100 1100 1100 1101
```

is:

```
0.000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0011…
```

while the (absolute value of the) difference between these two numbers:

```
-1.000 1100 1100 1100 1100 1100 1100…
-1.000 1100 1100 1100 1100 1100
```

is:

```
0.000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1100…
```

Since the former number is closer to the exact value, it is the used.

(Note:  Round-to-nearest, with ties to even low digit, is the usual default mode. Other rounding modes, such as truncation, may be available depending on the programming language and platform. Also, correctly rounding to the nearest value is recommended or required by the IEEE 754 standard and some programming languages, but some implementations may not do it correctly.)

Comment: Is any rule in the c/cpp standard that confirm the rounding mode?

Comment: @user8510613: The C standard makes recommendations but not complete requirements about rounding when converting decimal to floating-point. It does not even require that `1.1` and `1.10` convert to the same value.

Comment: @user8510613: ISO C doesn't even require that `float` or `double` use IEEE754 at all.  (As Eric says, 6.4.4.2 Floating constants leaves it implementation-defined what rounding is used for literals in the source; nearest and matching the result of run-time `strtod` is recommended but not required).  But there is a much stricter Annex F to the standard (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) which many modern implementations aim for.  **F.8.2 Translation**: `During translation the IEC 60559 default modes are in effect:  
 - The rounding direction mode is rounding to nearest`

Comment: Oops, this was a C++ question, not C.  Sorry, I think the ISO C++ standard has a very similar section for implementations that attempt to fully implement IEEE FP rules, but what I quoted was from the C11 standard.

Answer (score -3):

Certain 'double' literals cannot be exactly represented in memory.

The literal -1.1 seems to be one of those literals.

Comment: the OP already knew that and put the repeating `[0011]...` part in the question

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc, the question itself (from the OP) clearly indicates the OP did NOT know that the values would NOT be exact

Comment: No. He knows that the *binary representation of 1.1 is repeating*, so he must know that the representation is **not** exact. And he knows about `1.1f` which you seem don't know that's it's not a `double` literal. The OP did **not** ask why his 1.1 becomes `1.1000...003`or `0.99999...` but he's asking about the IEEE-754 form

Comment: FWIW, not "certain" literals: *most* floating point literals. And 1.1f is a float.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: "most" according to what distribution?  All integers up to 2^23, and some above that, are exactly representable, and so are numbers like `0.5` or `1.5`, i.e. where the denominator for the fraction is a power of 2.  If you mean out of numbers appearing in source code, integer FP constants are common, but so are approximations to `pi` and `e`, often written with extra decimal digits and not an exact representation of an FP bit-pattern.  So a significant fraction of FP literals in existing source code do need to be rounded at compile time, maybe even most.

Comment: If you know the highest representable value, you will see that most values in the same exponent range are not representable. Only in that range there are more not-representable integer values than the representable integers already.

Comment: @Peter: I may be off by a few, but the highest exponent is 126 (for float). That means that between the possible values in the 24 bits of the mantissa, there are gaps of 2^(126-23) = 2^103 *integer* values that are *not* exactly representable. In other words: most values in the entire range are *not* exactly representable.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Ok, so you're talking about a uniform distribution of integers over the full representable range.  Like I said, it depends on what distribution :P  Why limit it to integers, or to any range?  There's an uncountable infinity of unrepresentable real numbers between every representable float value (except `-0.0` and `+0.0`). And a countable infinity of integers outside the representable range.  But most numbers in computer programs are small. So I thought it would be interesting to think "most" literals that appear in source code. Your count of integers is interesting, too, though.

Comment: @PeterCordes: no matter what distribution you take (except for only the representable numbers), most numbers you will find in source code will not be exactly representable. That is what I meant.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: IDK, you find quite a lot of `10.0`, `2.0`, or `0.5`.  But you're probably right, there are lots of other constants like best-fit polynomial coefficients, as well as (fractions / multiples of) `pi` and `e`.  I don't think your argument about large integers with magnitude above 2^24 tells us much about real world source code, though.  I was already aware that the gaps between representable FP values grew to 2, then 4, then 8, etc. with larger exponents, but discounted that because such large constants are rare in source code.